# Export multiple plots into pdf in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am experiencing a problem exporting multiple plots to PDF in Python (jupyter notebook).

My code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df1 = df1['Subs']
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 200))
df1.plot()

df2 = df2['Subs']
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 200))
df2.plot()

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 13))
sns.heatmap(df3)
```

I have already tried several methods, but it seems like they don't work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html

Comment: @tom, I don't really understand how to implement it on my code. Can you show me it on my example?